# How can I get an object from select element via AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have **select** html element like this:

```
<select required="" ng-model="studentGroup">
<option value="" selected="">--select group--</option>
<option value="1">java 15-1</option>
<option value="2">java 15-2</option>
<option value="3">java 15-3</option>
</select>
```

I want to get an object - `studentGroup: {groupId:'1', groupName:'java 15-1'}`
when first option is selected(for example), 
where *groupId* - 'value' attribute of selected option, *groupName* - 'text' attribute.

How can I do this **using AngularJS**?

**UPDATE:**

It was solved as below:

```
<select ng-options="group.groupName for group in ctrl.groupList track by group.groupId" ng-model="ctrl.student.studentGroup"></select>
Selected studentGroup object: {{ctrl.studentGroup}}
```

where **ctrl** - my controller with *groupList* Array with *studentGroup* objects;
**studentGroup** - selected object as I wanted.

Comment: Yo want to get it outside of the Angular controller? Is that it?

Comment: nop, inside controller I have an object 'studentGroup' which I want to fill with selected data and save in DB (for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I have made an **example** the uses a **`<select>` element** ,**json array object to load values**, **custom directive** that listens change events and **calls controller function** to **give the selected object**.

plunkr example: http://plnkr.co/edit/iCS0blQjceA4tIIb8bUV?p=preview

### into html

```
{{selectedObj}}
<div class="col-xs-12 form-control"
         change-hall="filterHall(value)"
         items=items
         event-halls-list
         model='selectedObj'>

   </div>
```

### custom directive(name it as you like)

```
.directive('eventHallsList', function($timeout, $log, $http, $compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        changeHall: '&',
        items: '=',
        model: '='
      },
      templateUrl: 'mytemplate.tpl.html',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      }

    }
  });
```

[image]

Comment: Greate! Thanks for your answer!

Comment: It's a bit difficult explanation for my simple question.

Comment: It is an advanced example that you will face(some time)  if you intend to make a large web-application. Take your time and try to understand it because i use template, custom directive, and how we pass values from directive to controller. But is is corrent. you could tick it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with angular's ng-options directive. By declaring values for the select drop down in an array and iterating it with the help of [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) directive

```
$scope.studentGroups = [{
  id: 1,
  groupName: 'java 15-1'
}, {
  id: 2,
  groupName: 'java 15-2'
}];


<select ng-options="studentGroup as studentGroup.groupName for studentGroup in studentGroups track by studentGroup.id" ng-model="selected"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about that :

```
$scope.studentGroup = [
    { groupId: 1, groupName: 'java 15-1'},
    { groupId: 2, groupName: 'java 15-2'},
    { groupId: 3, groupName: 'java 15-3'},
    { groupId: 4, groupName: 'java 15-4'}
];

<select 
    ng-options="p.groupId + ' ' + p.groupName for p in studentGroup" ng-model="selectedPerson">
</select>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mdzmj2ks/)

Comment: I don't want to see ID as you did.. but  I got the main idea

Answer (score 0):

You can use the angular [`select` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) together with `ng-options`. This way you can provide arbitrary objects as values.